# Unfortunately Launcher3 has stopped working error in android studio?

Tags: android, android-emulator

When i run android program the emulator says unfortunately Launcher3 has stopped working. What is the reason or how can i fix the problem?

Answer (score 17):

1. Press the Apps menu button on your Android mobile phone device. It will display icons of all the apps installed on your mobile phone device.
   Press Settings.
2. Press Apps. (Pressing on Apps button will list down all the apps installed on your mobile phone.
3. Browse the Apps list and press on the app called "Launcher 3". (Launcher 3 is an app and it will be listed in the App list whenever you access Settings > Apps in your android phone).
4. Pressing on the "Launcher 3" app will open the "App info screen" which will show some details pertaining to that app. On this App info screen, you will find buttons like "Force Stop", "Uninstall", "Clear Data" and "Clear Cache" etc.
5. In Android Marshmallow (i.e. Android 6.0) choose Settings > Apps > Launcher3 > STORAGE. Press "Clear Cache". If this fails, press "Clear data". This will eventually restore functionality, but all custom shortcuts will be lost.

Restart the phone and its done. All the home screens along with app shortcuts will appear again and your mobile phone is at your service again.

I hope it explains well on how to solve the launcher problem in Android. Worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your help but  I am not saying for android phone i am saying android emulator in android studio.It doesn't work for emulator.

Comment: @TheBeginner an emulator is exactly the same as a device. You will have to go to Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager to design the exact (x86) device specs you need. In the android device choose the same menu using the steps listed above

Comment: I had to follow a slightly different workflow: 

App menu button (circle, centre bottom) > Swipe left > Settings > Launcher 3 > Storage > Clear Cache & Clear Data. Restart Phone

Comment: Edit your emulator setting in Graphics drop down select "Software-GLES2.0"

Answer (score 4):

I didn't found any particular answer to this question but i deleted the emulator and create a new one and increase the Ram size of the new emulator.Then the emulator works fine.

Answer (score 2):

May 2017; I had the same issue, could not even get to apps as it just cycled between starting and stopping. Went into avd settings, edited the multi core (unticked the box) and set graphics to software Gles. It appears to have fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a physical device. The problem was related with the fact that the google app ( the search bar for google on top ) was disabled. After the first reboot launcher3 began failing. No matter how many cache/data cleaning I did, it kept failing. 
I reenabled it and launched it, so it appeared again on the screen and from that moment on, launcher3 was back to life.

I guess there mmust be some kind of dependency with this app.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be relate to the graphics driver. In the emulator configuration, changing Emulated Graphics to `Software - GLES 2.0` caused the crashes to stop.